# Aggregate query for count for pivot table without using join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have following MySQL query that I am using in laravel for getting pivot table counts.

```
select tracks.*, track_play_counts.track_id, count(track_play_counts.id) as track_play
from tracks
join track_play_counts on tracks.id = track_play_counts.track_id 
group by track_id
order by track_play ;
```

it is taking too much time about 20 sec for larger amount of data. How can i reduce it?

I have already tried `withCount()` but it is used as filter query also so I can not use withCount here.

Is the way from that I can select particular field like `track_play` without using join? I realize that because of joining it is taking too much response time.

Comment: Have you indexed the foreign key??

Comment: yes, i already indexed foreign key. what can be the other reason for it?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Sample schema for what i want    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bac61a/5

Comment: Usually indexing is the solution. Everything of course depends on what is "larger amount of data" exactly.

Comment: Your query is utterly simple and if indexes are properly set as you said, you should probably neither change anything to it, nor have performance issues. The problem is thus elsewhere, like on the hardware or database design (table engine choice, lack of partitioning, etc...). If you want help, the very first thing to do is to show your tables' DDL and the EXPLAIN PLAN of this query. "Larger amount of data" is something that is not meaningful for us. Large amount for me is TRILLIONS, for you it might just be hundred of thousands, which is not "large".